Kernel Panic on boot of CentOS 7 working system on installing new NVME SSD
I have an existing CentOS 7 (7.6.1810) system running on AMD.  It works well, currently running with the core O/S on a SATA SSD.  I decided to attempt to add more storage by installing a new Samaung 990 EVO NVME SSD.
After installing the new drive and rebooting, grub properly starts the kernel boot, but the kernel panics almost immediately.  I'm not sure what is the real issue here - I wonder if it may be one of the following:

The new drive changing the device order causing a problem for the kernel (perhaps failing to properly locate the boot drive?)
The new drive is faulty
The kernel does not support the new drive
BIOS settings need to be updated
???

Here is the panic dump (NOTE this was captured by taking a picture, using an image-to-text tool online and then manually fixing it up; it may not be 100% correct):
[   0.000000] Warning: AMD Processor - this hardware has not undergone upstream
testing. Please consult http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ for more information
[   0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
[   5.011991] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   5.012005] kernel BUG at include/linux/dma-attrs.h:53!
[   5.012012] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP
[   5.012022] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi(+) snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep btusb snd_seq btrtl snd_seq_device btbcm btintel snd_pcm cfg88211 bluetooth snd_timer pcspkr snd ccp soundcore k10temp sg rfkill nvme nvme_core i2c_piix4 sdhci_acpi sdhci mmc_core i2c_designware_platform gpio_amdpt pinctrl_amd iosf_mbi i2c_designware_core acpi_cpufreq ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic nouveau crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common crc32c_intel video mxm_wmi drm_kms_helper serio_raw syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ttm igb ahci drm libahci r8169 ptp pps_core dca mii i2c_algo_bit libata drm_panel_orientation_quirks wmi dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod
[   5.012215] CPU: 11 PID: 1246 Comm: kworker/u64:8 Not tainted 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1
[   5.012225] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./X370 Killer SLI/ac, BIOS P5.40 07/03/2019
[   5.012235] Workqueue: nvme-reset-uq nvme_reset_work [nvme]
[   5.012242] task: ffff9337d73ab0c0 ti: ffff932cce198000 task.ti: ffff932cce198000
[   5.012249] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc08e63bf>] [<ffffffffc08e63bf>] nvme_reset_work+0xf6f/0xfbd [nvme]
[   5.012261] RSP: 0018:ffff932cce19bd40 EFLAGS: 00010206
[   5.012267] RAX: ffff9337cc226c00 RBX: ffff9337d9b23568 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   5.012274] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff9337cc226c80
[   5.012280] RBP: ffff932cce19be18 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff9337cc226c00
[   5.012286] R10: ffff93297fc03900 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000400000
[   5.012293] R13: 0000000000000010 R14: 0000000000000010 R15: ffff9337ccee6000
[   5.012300] FS:  00007f4c2f778740(0000) GS:ffff93381eac0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   5.012307] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   5.012312] CR2: 00007ffe0e594330 CR3: 0000000fd9380000 CR4: 00000000003407e0
[   5.012318] Call Trace:
[   5.012328] [<ffffffffb1ad33bf>] ? ttwu_do_activate+0x6f/0x80
[   5.012336] [<ffffffffb1ad68a0>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x190/0x390
[   5.012345] [<ffffffffb1ab9ebf>] process_one_work+0x17f/0x440
[   5.012352] [<ffffffffb1abaf56>] worker_thread+0x126/0x3c0
[   5.012360] [<ffffffffb1abae30>] ? manage_workers.isra.25+0x2a0/0x2a0
[   5.012367] [<ffffffffb1ac1da1>] kthread+0xd1/0xe0
[   5.012373] [<ffffffffb1ac1cd0>] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40
[   5.012382] [<ffffffffb2175c24>] ret_from_fork_nospec_begin+0xe/0x21
[   5.012389] [<ffffffffb1ac1cd0>] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40
[   5.012395] Code: 48 c7 83 58 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 e9 9d fa ff ff 48 83 bd 40 ff ff ff 00 0f 84 e3 fc ff ff 48 c7 45 90 00 00 00 00 0f ba 6d 90 04 <0f> 0b 4c 89 ef 41 be f4 ff ff ff e8 al c1 46 f1 e9 fe f0 ff ff
[   5.012535] RIP  [<ffffffffc08e63bf>] nvme_reset_work+0xf6f/0xfbd [nvme]
[   5.012544] RSP <ffff932cce19bd40>
[   5.012565] --[ end trace 27d62d0ce0030f0f ]---
[   5.012570] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[   5.012782] Kernel Offset: 0x30a00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)


Another possibility: Samsung 990 is not supported by the hardware. What PC? Also, test booting from USB with a Live Linux distro; if the extra drive is not recognized, it's likely a hardware issue.

It's a custom-built machine.  MSI Z370M MB.  If it were not supported by the hardware, wouldn't it be more likely to just not show up at all?

Checking the MB page, compatible devices lists 970 EVO but not 990 EVO...  I suspect it is compatible.

Oh, this SSD is PCI-E 4.0 but the MB only shows support for PCI-E Gen3.

On further research, it appears that should work.  I could really use some help deciphering the error message / stack trace.
